# there is a warning message when I purge cache in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla2.5

any one have a solution for this..

WARNING: This can be resource intensive on sites with large number of items!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be its helps you in joomla2.5 purge cach warrning

http://docs.joomla.org/Help25:Site_Maintenance_Purge_Expired_Cache

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/caching/clear-cache

http://brian.teeman.net/joomla/774-upgrading-to-joomla-2-5-some-warnings

read it and try it...